# Ajax missunderstanding, or an error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Can you please explain me how should i use `Ajax` properly.
I have an easy example in `Asp.Net MVC`:

This is my layout view

```
<html>
<head>
//scripts
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img id="LogoImg" src="http://www.ruralcomshow.com/wpontent/uploads/2014/06/Midwest-Data-Center-Logo-175x75.png" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left-side">
           //some navigation
        </div>
        <div id="right-side">
            @RenderBody()

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="clearfix">
        //some footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public PartialViewResult Ajax()
  {
    return PartialView();
  }

  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

This is Ajax partial view:

```
 <h2>This is how it's done</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("back :C","Index","Home")
```

This is Index view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Ajax.ActionLink("Go, go Ajax!", "Ajax", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "right-side", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace})
```

So, as I understood when i click `Ajax ActionLink` my whole page should not `rerender`, and the only thing that should change is `div with id "right-side"`? So the problem is that the whole page always gets rerendered.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a problem of my understanding?

Comment: have you included jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file..??

Comment: sure, it works fine, div element changes in a proper way, the only problem is rerendering of the whole page.

Comment: just try below answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include jquery and unobtrusive-ajax  at the bottom of the page as shown :-

```
</footer>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```